# Adding class on first click and scroll down on second click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First click on button will add a new HTML class like `.btn-next` and after second (and more times) click this will scroll down to section with an HTML id.

I tried to add class `.btn-next` on first click and second time this will animate and scroll down to section, but it is not working.

```
$('.btn-toggle-1').on('click',function() {
    $('.btn-toggle-1 span').text('Idem do toho (70 €)');
    $('.tabs').slideDown();
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','white').addClass('btn-next');

    $('.fcprice').attr("placeholder", "Online tréner za 70 € s DPH");
})

$('.btn-next').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section-contact").offset().top-100
    }, 800);
})
```

HTML code for button (is on bottom):

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 box box-1">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link bal1 active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">mesačný</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link bal2" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">2-mesačný</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="pl-0 tab-list">
                    <li>1x tréningový plán</li>
                    <li>stravovací program</li>
                    <li>online komunikácia počas celej spolupráce</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                <ul class="pl-0 tab-list">
                    <li>2x tréningový plán</li>
                    <li>stravovací program</li>
                    <li>online komunikácia počas celej spolupráce</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-toggle-1 button wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s"><span>Chcem makať doma</span></button>
</div>
```

HTML for `.section-contact` where is input with class `.fcprice` located:
(Some lines was removed to not spam)

```
<section id="section-contact" class="page-section wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
    <form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MENO" name="fname" required>

        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-MAIL" name="email" required>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="VEK" name="age">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="PLATBA BANKOVÝM PREVODOM" name="payment" required>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PRIEZVISKO" name="lname">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TELEFÓN" name="phone">

        <label id="img_category_label" class="form-control field" for="img_category" data-value="">......</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control fcprice" placeholder="" readonly disabled>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-toggler"><span>Záväzne objednať</span></button>
    </form>
</section>
```

What is wrong?
Many thanks!

EDIT: I have added HTML code.

Comment: Can you share your relevant HTML, enough so that we can take your "*[mcve]*" code and form something we can work with that reproduces - the core of - your problem?

Comment: Why we need the HMTL here: Dynamic addition and then use of a class - we need the HTML to best advise you how to handle this - as it is your click handler for `.btn-next` is only attached to the currently present ones.  Note there are better/great ways to handle this but it would depend upon your HTML.

Comment: No reason to do this if you are then adding a class: `$(this).css('backgroundColor','white')`

Comment: Yes, I added HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because your code is always getting the first function (first click), because this is the primary one, just with some other class on the button. You can check if the button has or not your `btn-next` class and do your condidition. You can try this:

```
$('.btn-toggle-1').on('click',function() {
    $('.btn-toggle-1 span').text('Idem do toho (70 €)');
    $('.tabs').slideDown();

    if($(this).hasClass('btn-next')){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#section-contact").offset().top-100
        }, 800);
    }else{
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','white').addClass('btn-next');
        $('.fcprice').attr("placeholder", "Online tréner za 70 € s DPH");
    }
});
```

Comment: This may/will fail in certain cases but no way to know without the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that because, both click is at the ame element the first definition of click overwrite the second when you want to scroll it.

try this code :

```js
$('.btn-toggle-1').on('click',function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('btn-next')) {
          $('.btn-toggle-1 span').text('Idem do toho (70 €)');
          $('.tabs').slideDown();
          $(this).css('backgroundColor','white').addClass('btn-next');
          $('.fcprice').attr("placeholder", "Online tréner za 70 € s DPH");
        } else {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#section-contact").offset().top-100
          }, 800);
        }
    });
```

```css
#section-contact{
  margin-top:1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-toggle-1"><span>boton</span></button>
<p class="cprice">demo</p>
<div id="section-contact">element at scroller</div>
```

Comment: This may/will fail in certain cases but no way to know without the HTML

Comment: have you clicked twice?